# Replacing Part of A String with Dot Symbols?

Tags: java, android, textview, passwords

I'm aware that I can use the following below to replace an entire string with dot symbols (i.e. passwords):

```
TextView textView1.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

such that a String like "password" will turn to "••••••••"

But is there a function that replaces only part of the string while still showing the rest (i.e. credit card numbers):

For example, I want to turn "1234567890" into "••••••7890"

Answer (score 0):

You posted the answer yourself-  use a TransformationMethod.  Write a custom TransformationMethod class, and pass that to the view

Comment: Yes.  The transformation class is meant to be extended-  that's why you can set one, and why its an abstract class.

Comment: I'm having trouble how to actually start it, I've looked at the developer Android site and all it states is the function.  Do I pass parameters in the method?

Comment: You write a function getTransformation(CharSequence source, View view) and have it return a CharSequence with the text you want displayed.  Here's the code of PasswordTransformationMethod as an example:   http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/text/method/PasswordTransformationMethod.java